# S3 user-specific directory access using aws cognito authentication

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have an asp.net core api. 
Authentication offloaded to cognito.
I have an s3 bucket which has two root folders.
`/Account` and `/Data`

1. I want all authenticated users to have access to `/Data`.
2. My account folders will be in format of `/Account/UserX/More` data...

I want to grant cognito authenticated users access to only their specific Account folder and subfolders.

How do I achieve this segregation and keep each users’ data separate from each other?

How would I achieve 1 & 2 above?